# Which is the better way to compare Flags Enum?

Tags: c#

Normally when comparing flag enums I use the following format:

```
(value & flag) == flag;
```

But sometimes I come across this:

```
(value & flag) != 0;
```

Just wondering which is the better to use, or does it come down to personal preference?

Comment: I replaced usage of any these (including `Enum.HasFlag`) with separate helper methods which produces a much cleaner API usage and reduces code duplication. See: http://hugoware.net/blog/enumeration-extensions-2-0 Since I started using a modification of Hugo's extensions, things feel a lot nicer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So long as `flag` is a one-bit flag, they are equivalent.  If `flag` has multiple bits,

```
(value & flag) == flag;
```

is a logical AND (ALL bits must match) while

```
(value & flag) != 0;
```

is a logical OR (ANY of the bits must match).

Answer (score 18):

if you are using .net 4 or higher use [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) instead

In fact this method uses first way of checking, but provide more clear way to check flags

Comment: Which is slower than the operations above!

Comment: Yes, it might be slower, but most of the cases it doesn't make sense, if we look from the point of view performance vs. clear code

Comment: Note that this method is equivalent to the first line in the Original Post. If `flag` is not a single-bit value (i.e. not a power of 2, or `MinValue` for signed underlying integer), that's important (cf. other answers).

Comment: yes, it just hide the first line behind the method and do some checks. Added to the post, thanks

Comment: Thank you for saving me headaches with this obvious thing :)

Answer (score 4):

It's just about personal preference.

The performance of the two will be approximately identical, and the result will always be identical.  (Assuming a single-threaded environment.)

The second example copy/pastes a bit more easily I guess.

The second example is also a tad less vunerable to cross threading issues (if `flag` is mutated in the middle of the expression weird things could happen in the first).

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking value against composite flag, like for example value: `0x0111`, flags: `0x0101` then `(value & flags) == flags` means "all flags are set", and `(value & flags) != 0` means "any flag is set".

Comment: Upvoted, but you should edit to put in the needed parentheses.